# My Java code will not run, why? (Only a few lines)

Tags: java

I had to write this for a class project. I don't get any errors when compiling, but the program won't run when I attempt to execute it.

We have to write a program myRandomWalkers.java that takes two command-line arguments N and T. In each of T independent experiments, simulate a random walk of N steps and compute the squared distance. Output the mean squared distance (the average of the T squared distances).

I wrote the following:

```
public class myRandomWalkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int t= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int x= 0; // starting x position
        int y= 0; // starting y position
        int sum = 0; // for calculating mean square distance
        double r;

        int count = 0;
        while (count <= t)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

                r= Math.random();
                if (r<=0.25) x++;
                else if(r<=0.50) x--;
                else if(r<=0.75) y++;
                else if(r<=1.0) y--;        

                int z = ((x*x) + (y*y));
                sum +=z;
            }
        }

        int average = (sum/t);
        System.out.println ("mean squared distance = " + average);
    }        
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the most appropriate place for this.

Comment: @Vikdor In this case there is a bug (program does not terminate) so I suppose it can be asked on SO too... Although it could be argued that the question is too localized...

Comment: I voted to close based on the title but it isn't really a code review question. It's more about finding a bug or an issue and therefore a better fit for SO. (I updated the OP's title to better reflect this IMO.)

Comment: I too commented based on the title and now I see that it's been updated to reflect the intent of the description.

Comment: "the program won't run" is far too vague. What happens? Please give details of what you're trying and the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output will depend on the arguments you pass to your program. However:

- if `count > t` the while loop will not be executed
- if `count <= t` the while loop will never end because you don't increment count - you probably need to add a `count++;` somewhere in your while loop.

Comment: I added count++ after the for loop closes but still in the while loop, still having the same issue :/

Comment: @Ryan Without knowing what inputs you use, it is difficult to reproduce what you see and therefore difficult to help you further.

Comment: @Ryan For example, for n = 5 and t = 1, after adding `count++` right after the for loop, I get the following output: "mean squared distance = 25"

Comment: after adding count++ I got it to worked, was getting sloppy and running an older version...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As assylias has said, the exit condition of your while loop will never be reached because `count` never changes.

However i'd also comment on the fact that you have used 2 different loops where the situation for both is fairly similar. Some would argue that which type of loop you use here is personal preference but using 2 different styles doesn't make sense. I tend t use the principle that if I know how many iterations there will be then use a for loop (so anything that is using a counter would qualify)

Other consideration (for extra credit) could be to have a look a your parseInt calls, I believe negative numbers will go through fine but you're calculations won't consider them. And also non numerics could easily be passed in to the command line, what would your program do then? What would you prefer it did?